# Magento2 Composer require package doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, centos, composer-php, magento2, whm

on command line -
I am using this command:

```
/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer require apptrian/image-optimizer:2.2.0
```

after that I get this on screen:

```
Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

but when I actually check the composer.json file, I don't see any changes.
and running composer update I get:

```
[root@s132-148-137-252 public_html]# /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

when I check php -v using

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php -v
```

I get

```
PHP 7.0.31 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2018 21:29:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.31, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

**but If I check simply php -v**

**Then I get - which is not correct as it returns - (cgi-fcgi)**

```
ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.0.31 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 23 2018 21:29:24)
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.31, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

How can correct both the issues that is get composer to work as well as `php-cli` issue.

Comment: You have to run the composer command for a specific cPanel user not as root. Where exactly is located that composer.json file (like full path)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is incorrectly configured and it is using SAPI PHP for CLI calls. You should run Composer using PHP for CLI explicitly:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer require apptrian/image-optimizer:2.2.0
```

---

BTW: You should take this warning about running composer as root seriously - this may create security issues.